# Security negotiation exception in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

Consider:

[image]

I'm getting this error while connection to a WCF service. I have WCF username and password authentication in the WCF service. I want clients to require a username and password to connect to this service. This is my service configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NewBinding0">
                <security>
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfUserNamePasswordAuthentication.Service1Behavior"
                 name="WcfUserNamePasswordAuthentication.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfUserNamePasswordAuthentication.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfUserNamePasswordAuthentication.Service1Behavior">

                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to
                     false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment. -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging
                     purposes, set the value below to true. Set to false
                     before deployment to avoid disclosing exception
                     information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

                <serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceCertificate findValue="CertMohan"
                                        storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                                        storeName="My"
                                        x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
                                            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfUserNamePasswordAuthentication.UserNameAuthentication, WcfUserNamePasswordAuthentication"
                    />
                </serviceCredentials>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this is my client configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
               openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
               bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
               textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">

                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                 maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                 enabled="false" />

                <security mode="Message">

                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                     algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://abc31.org.in/WcfUserName/Service1.svc"
           binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
           contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">

            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And this way I am connecting to my service:

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client sc = new WebApplication3.ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("localhost");
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();

binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Message;

binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Mohan";
sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Sharma";
lblRecord.Text = sc.GetData(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DnsEndpointIdentity` cannot be `localhost`. It must be subject name of the certificate which is in your case `CertMohan`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. It didn't work. still same error is coming.

Comment: Did you change it on both server and client? Is certificate trusted by the client?

Comment: It's test certificate created by selfcert. i changed it on both sides.

Comment: although my problem is as it was, i am marking it as answer because it was something that could also create error. is there anything you can figure out?